# getElementById returning null but returns DOM node with $("")

Tags: javascript

I have the following lines in my `.js` file `canvas.js` in my RoR `/assets/javascripts/` directory.

```
var b_canvas = document.getElementById("prof_canvas");
console.log(b_canvas);
```

Which when executed in my browser's console returns.

```
null
```

But when I write the following in the Console:

```
$("#prof_canvas")
```

I get back the `<canvas>` object.

Here is the HTML upon which the JS operates:

```
 <canvas id='prof_canvas' style='width:400px;height:300px '></canvas>
```

Comment: Timing matters. It means the the corresponding jQuery snippet is executed when the element is added to DOM.

Comment: is there a vanilla JS equivalent to `document.ready()`

Comment: Put your script link  in the bottom of your  html code.

Comment: Use `window.onload` to execute the same line JS, and see what are the results.

Comment: @Thalatta Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery**:

```
$("#prof_canvas")
```

Is actually mirror of `querySelector`:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#prof_canvas");
```

And better is to add an script like this at the end of your HTML or code the event when DOM is ready:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded